# Android NDK: Directive not visible to includes of static library

Tags: android, linker, android-ndk, build-system, android.mk

I simply want use a static library for an NDK project. The library works with build systems like automake, but in Android.mk I have a problem with the source files. For some reason, directives don't work over different header files and I get the following error:

```
error: 'myname' does not name a type
```

It seems that the directive defined in file1.hpp is not visible in file2.hpp which includes file1.hpp (as I said, this problem does not occur with other build systems like automake.

What am I doing wrong here?

Android.mk:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := libstat

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lm

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := /home/dir/libstat.a

LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := /home/dir/src

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)





include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := hello-jni

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -lm -ldl /home/dir/src

LOCAL_LDFLAGS := -L/home/dir/

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += /home/dir/src

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello-jni.cpp

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -ggdb

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libstat

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

src includes all header and source files. Any hint would be appreciated.